# Prevent goroutine from executing

Tags: go

I have a function as follows:

```
func keepConnUp(n netAddr, w chan<- io.Writer, err chan error) {
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", n.Addr, n.Port)
    for {
        <-err
        time.Sleep(reconnectTimer)
        conn, _ := net.Dial(n.Network, addr)
        w <- conn
    }
}
```

The goal is to redial a connection when I receive an error from a `err chan`. But I don't want to redial if I'm already dialing or within a certain time duration. However I may receive alot of errors I don't want to block.

How could I do that?

**EDIT**

Solution I've implemented so far :

```
func keepConnUp(n netAddr, w chan<- io.Writer, err chan error) {
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", n.Addr, n.Port)
    done := make(chan bool)

    isDialing := false

    for {
        select {
        case <-err:
            if !isDialing {
                isDialing = true
                time.AfterFunc(reconnectTimer, func() {
                    done <- true
                })
                
            }
        case <-done:
            conn, _ := net.Dial(n.Network, addr)
            w <- conn
            isDialing = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting requirements. On the one hand, you say you don't want to redial when dialing in progress. On the other, you say you don't want to block. Can you explain what you mean by these two things, since they seem to contradict each other?

Comment: if you want to re-dail, does this imply the connection gets dropped? Otherwise, I'm having difficulties to understand why you'd re-establish a connection on *some error*

Comment: Yes, errors comes from a connection dropped.

I can try to add context Flimzy. I receive 10 errors. On the first error I get, I want to redial a connection. I don't want further errors to trigger a redial if they occur within 10 seconds. But I don't want to block the channel from listening to errors.

Comment: I've implemented a solution, I'd like to have feedback if you have time for it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure that there is only one call to redial after errors.

Comment: I'm afraid a waitgroup would prevent receiving further error. I want to receive all errors, but act differently if within a given timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Conn struct {
    conn net.Conn
    dialing bool
    mu sync.Mutex
}

func (c Conn) Dial() {
    c.mu.Lock()
    if c.dialing {
        c.mu.Unlock()
        return
    }
    c.dialing = true
    c.mu.Unlock()
    time.AfterFunc(reconnectTimer, func() {
        c.conn, _ := net.Dial(n.Network, addr)
        w <- c.conn
        c.dialing = false
    })
}
```

now you can call `Conn.Dial()` in a go routine

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I worked on Go but I took a stab at making it work using `context.Context` and `sync.Once`. I have **not** tested this though.

```
func keepConnUp(n netAddr, w chan<- io.Writer, err chan error) {
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", n.Addr, n.Port)
    done := make(chan bool)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    cancel() // So that ctx.Err() returns non-nil on the first try
    once := sync.Once{}

    for {
        <-err
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            once.Do(func() {
                conn, _ := net.Dial(n.Network, addr)
                w <- conn
            })
            once = sync.Once{} // Reset once
            ctx = context.WithTimeout(reconnectTimer) // Reset context timeout
        }
    }
}
```